# How to eliminate series of values with so much variation

Tags: matlab, dataset

I got a dataset (azimuth vs time) with measure the compass of an object trough time. So I can see when the object is moving (the compass vary so much), and when it's static, without moving (compass do not vary). My question is how to program this in matlab in order to eliminate the data which show that the object is moving and just filter data that shows the object is static.

For example:

Azimuth (angle) | 30  30  30 15 10 16 19 24 24 24 17 14 12 15 16

Time (s)    | 1   2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

The output would be:

Azimuth (angle) | 30  30  30 24 24 24

Time (s)    | 1   2   3   8  9 10

Comment: What output do you expect? Would be something based on `diif(Azimuth)==0` or `diif(Azimuth)<=tolerance`

Comment: @Daniel, I was thinking something similar too, I guess it's the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s=diff(Azumuth)==0
%diff only would skip the values at t=1 and t=8. Modify to include them as well:
s=[s(1),s(2:end)|s(1:end-1),s(end)]
Azumuth(s)
Time(s)
```